# Phonegap Push Notification possible?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to implementate push notification in my phonegap (android, ios) project. The user should get a message whenever there is an update on an event.

I have a problem with understanding the way this is done.

How can i "check for updates" while my app is not running?
Is this even possible with phonegap?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap- Support for push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933209/phonegap-support-for-push-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a problem with understanding the way this is done.

As you may know, [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) the open source version) is just an application that wraps your website mimicking a real app. When the app is not running, your website is also not running. If you want to get a notification this cannot be done in the webiste.

What you can do is use PhoneGap to talk with the Operating System (iOS or Android) and register your notification. You can do that either writing a specific plugin in PhoneGap or using an existing one like [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

This plugin has basically three steps:

**1) Creation** - Initialise for different Operating Systems

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ 
       "android": {"senderID": "12345679"},
       "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"},
       "windows": {} 
     });
```

**2) Register** - When is your notification being triggered

```
push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});
```

**3) Action** - What to do when this happens

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers in the (nearly) duplicate question I want to mention two more things.

You could try to use websockets. An implementation like [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) will let you "push" data from your server to all or selected clients.

BUT: As your mentioned, if your app is in background, deep sleep or off, websocket may fail to deliver the data.

Therefor you'll have to use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or a similar service. These kind of services all use cordova plugins that register a background service along with your app that is capable of receiving push notifications even if your app is not running.